# Swift: EXC_BAD_ACCESS calling a method from a generic type that implements a protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, protocols

I'm working on a project with Swift 2 and Xcode 7.3 and facing an error that I can't understand the reason yet.

I've created a protocol called `Resource` which has an `associatedtype` and a `static var` of that type.

Inside its extension, I'm trying to create a default implementation of the `static var`'s getter, where the type is a generic `struct` that implements another `protocol` called `ResourceFinderProtocol`.

It all compiles good but, in runtime, when executing the last line of the snippet below, it produces a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.

If I make the `struct ResourceFinder` not generic, it works smoothly.

```
protocol Resource {
    associatedtype ResourceFinderType
    static var localObjects: ResourceFinderType { get }
}

extension Resource {
    static var localObjects: ResourceFinder<Self> {
        return ResourceFinder()
    }
}

public protocol ResourceFinderProtocol {
    associatedtype ResourceType
    func all() -> [ResourceType]
}

struct ResourceFinder<T:Resource>: ResourceFinderProtocol {
    func all() -> [T] {
        return []
    }
}

struct Model: Resource {}

Model.localObjects.all()
```

Any ideas of what can be happening here?

**EDIT:**

As Alexander pointed out, even if I split the call into:

```
let localObjects = Model.localObjects
let allObjects = localObjects.all()
```

... it still crashes in the first line.

Comment: By the way, `Model.localObjects` also crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a compiler bug, resulting in a stack overflow when accessing the `localObjects` property. From what I can gather, it is an issue with a recursive dependency between your types, and more specifically that `localObjects` is invoked via dynamic dispatch. If I remove the `static var localObjects: ResourceFinderType { get }` from `Resource` it works.

Alternatively, if you remove the `Resource` constraint from `ResourceFinder`, it will also run successfully.

I have reported the issue and you can track it via [SR-1314](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1314)

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue, Stuart. They already marked as resolved as it seems to be fixed on master. So the fix comes in the next release.

Comment: I confirmed it works with with the 04-25 3.0 SNAPSHOT too